# how unite two functions in to one in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have this react functional component, I have a problem with the rest function inside of it I have to call this function twice to change every single state any way to unite them in to one ? in classic JavaScript I would use a conditional but since I am new to react I have no clue how to achieve this yet ?

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function ChangeableItem(props) {

    setNumber([props.number])
    setDescribe([props.dsecribe])
    }
    
    const restNumber = (e)=> {
        setNumber('') 
    }
    const restDescribe = (e)=> {
        setDescribe('')
    }
  
    return (
    <li className='day-item'>
    <div className='number amount' onFocus={() =>{restNumber();}}} contentEditable="true">{number}</div>
    <div className='number name'  onFocus={() =>{restDescribe();}}} contentEditable="true">{describe}</div>
    <div className="">
    {icons}
    </div>
    </li>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, you can use `useEffect` on this, like you store your value in a `useState` and retrieve it in a `useEffect`

such as:

```js
const [num, setNum] = React.useState('');
const [desc, setDesc] = React.useState('');


// these functions will retrieve values for you,
// when retrieving is done, it will set value to useState so you can use it.
React.useEffect(()=>{
  restNumber([props.number])
// assuming this function return a Promise
   .then((val)=>{
  setNum(val);
})

},[props.number])


React.useEffect(()=>{
  restDescription([props.description])
// assuming this function return a Promise
   .then((val)=>{
  setDesc(val);
})

},[props.description])
```

EDIT:

if you really want to retrieve value on focus, you can just do

```js
<div onFocus={()=>restNumber([props.number]).then((val)=>setNum(val))}>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` to update new props:

```
useEffect(() => setNumber(props.number), [props.number])
useEffect(() => setDescribe(props.dsecribe), [props.dsecribe])
```

Comment: is there any other way with in the onFoucs ?